# Ignore a row in SQL if one column value is equal and another column is not equal

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table, where SL is unique value, Number column can have 2 type either A or B. I want to ignore the number having Type B when same number also has Type A.

```
SL  Number  Type
1   101     A
2   102     A
3   102     B
4   103     A
5   104     B
```

Expected Result

```
SL  Number  Type
1   101     A
2   102     A
4   103     A
5   104     B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.SL, t1.Number, t1.Type
FROM mytable t1
WHERE t1.Type = 'A' OR NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM mytable t2
   WHERE t2.Number = t1.Number AND t2.Type = 'A'
)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f80d7/1)

**Explanation:**

The query selects *all* `A` rows due to

```
t1.Type = 'A'
```

and *all* `B` rows *provided that* the sbuquery of the `NOT EXISTS` operator returns *no* rows. This subquery

```
SELECT 1
FROM mytable t2
WHERE t2.Number = t1.Number AND t2.Type = 'A' -- t1 is a reference to the outer table
```

returns a row if an `A` record, having the same `Number` as the `B` record, exists.

Comment: Thanks  this is working fine for above table having 3 column. But my table have more column and i am using those values for filter.  Can you please explain how this query is working so that i can extend this for my query

Answer (score 0):

'B' is bigger than 'A'.
So a smaller Type must not exist.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM yourtable dup
   WHERE dup.Number = t.Number
     AND dup.Type < t.Type
)
```

This way the smallest type per number will be selected. Even with extra types.